# R ggplot not displaying

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know this question has been asked a number of times, but the solutions for those answers did not work for me.  I am using R version 4.0.0 in R studio.  I have been able to use ggplot before I updated, so I am not sure if that is related to the issue or not.

I am trying with one of the ggplot examples:

```
library("ggplot2")
p1<- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
     geom_point()
show(p1)
```

I have also tried

```
print(p1)
```

Neither have shown the plot nor thrown an error.  I am putting this directly into the console, so from what I've read, the print/show *shouldn't* be necessary, but it still does not show. P1 is created in my Global Environment and is a List of 9.  Does anyone have any ideas???  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you have redirected the output by opening a pdf() or jpeg() device that you have forgotten to close ?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my issue (smf). Thanks!